# Finding a 1-parameter family of solutions for $2xy\ dx + (x^2 + y^2)\ dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to use the steps in  [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.gh/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=iU4zDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (Lesson 7B page 60) to find a 1-paremter family of solutions for

$$2xy\ dx + (x^2 + y^2)\ dy = 0$$

Assuming that $dy \neq 0$

This is what I tried:

$$ 2xy\ dx + (x^2 + y^2)dy = 0 $$

$$ y^2\bigg(\frac{2x}{y}\bigg) \ dx + y^2\bigg(\frac{x^2}{y^2} + 1\bigg)dy = 0 \quad y \neq 0$$

$$ \text{let } x = uy \implies dx = u\ dy + y\ du$$

$$ \text{substituting } dx $$

$$ y^2\bigg(\frac{2x}{y}\bigg) \ (u \ dy + y \ du) + y^2\bigg(\frac{x^2}{y^2} + 1\bigg)dy = 0 $$

Letting $u = \frac {x}{y}$ and simplifying

$$ (2u^2 + u^2 + 1) \ dy + 2uy \ du $$

$$ \frac{dy}{2uy} + \frac{du}{2u^2 + u^2 + 1} = 0 $$

$$ \int \frac{1}{2uy} dy + \int \frac{1}{2u^2 + u^2 + 1} du = 0 $$

Comment: It's an exact differential

Comment: You can substitute $v=x^2y$ if you prefer then you get $\int dv=-\int y^2dy$

Comment: @Isham I see you are really helping. But I don't know why $dx^2 = 2x \ dx$. I tried doing my integration but I didn't get an answer like yours.

Comment: Rewrite it as $\frac {dx^2}{dx}=2x$  you just differentiate $x^2$ wrt $x$

Comment: @Isham Yes your answer is correct.

Comment: You should substitute $v=x^2y$ if you want to solve it. Because then $dv=2xydx+x^2dy$ Then it's separable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve it as a homogeneous differential equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = {-2xy\over x^2+y^2}$$

Let $y=vx \implies y’=v’x+v$

$$\implies v’x+v = {-2x^2v\over x^2(1+v^2)}={-2v\over 1+v^2}$$

$$\implies {xdv\over dx} = -{v^3+v+2v\over 1+v^2}$$

$$\implies \int{dx\over x} =\int - {1+v^2\over v(v^2+3)}dv $$

By partial fraction decomposition we have the RHS’s integrand as $$-\left({1\over 3v}+{2v\over 3(v^2+3)}\right)$$

Integrating we get

$$\ln(kx) = -\frac13(\ln v+\ln(v^2+3))$$

$$\implies \frac1{k^3x^3} = {y^3\over x^3} + 3{y\over x}$$

$$\implies \boxed{y^3+3x^2y = c}$$

(Where $c$ is an arbitrary constant, related to the earlier introduced arbitrary constant of integration k as $c=\frac1{k^3}$)

Comment: How did you get the last $ \frac {1}{k^3x^3} = \frac{y^3}{x^3} + 3\frac{y}{x} $

Comment: Multiply both sides by $-3$ and use $a\ln b=\ln b^a$, $\ln s + \ln t = \ln st$ and $\ln p= \ln q \iff p = q$.

Comment: after multiplying I had $ln(kx)^{-3} = (ln v +ln(v^2 + 3) \implies \frac{1}{k^3x^3} = v + v^2 + 3$

Comment: $\ln s + \ln t = \ln st$, not $\ln s+t$. Note that $e^se^t=e^{s+t}$ and $\ln x $ is just the inverse of $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

The differential is exact.
$$2xy\ dx + (x^2 + y^2)\ dy = 0$$
You have that $dx^2=2xdx$
$$y\ dx^2 + x^2dy + y^2 dy = 0$$
And also $y\ dx^2 + x^2dy=dx^2y$:
$$dx^2y + \frac 1 3 dy^3  = 0$$
Integrate.
$$\boxed{x^2y + \dfrac { y^3}3  = C}$$

---

**Edit**:

$$\frac {dx^2y}{dx}=x^2\frac {dy}{dx}+2xy$$
So that:
$$ {dx^2y}=x^2 {dy}+2xy{dx}$$
And for $y^3$ we have
$$\frac {dy^3}{dx}=3y^2\frac {dy}{dx}$$
So that we can write:
$$ {dy^3}=3y^2 {dy}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But please I don't really understand what you have written. I am now learning it. I will be happy if you can follow the steps in the book for me

Comment: I don't own that book ufortunately ..I can add some lines in my answer  @EALehn

Comment: that will also be helpful

Comment: The book uses the same method with a product of functions which the author differentiate. The same here just choose as a product of txo functions $v=x^2y$ @EALehn